# add a service to a cdk PolicyStatement principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

how do I make Elasticsearch my principal in my policy statement using python cdk?

[image]

trying to recreate this policy in a more pythonic way [image]

....................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add Amazon service as a principal, this should do the trick;

```
iam.PolicyStatement(
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            principals=[iam.ServicePrincipal("es.amazonaws.com")],
            actions=['sts:AssumeRole'],
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_iam/ServicePrincipal.html